# Where did the Mt.gox Trustee sell his 400 million worth of bitcoin?

Tags: mtgox, sell-bitcoins

Is there a way to figure out where did the Mt.gox trustee sell his bitcoins? Was it on typical exchanges we use today or was it through a private big exchange?

Comment: I don't have Nobuaki Kobayashi's contact info but apparently the MtGox Trustee Help Desk at 011 81-3-4588-3922 in Japan can pass a message along to him.  You might try asking there.  Note 011 is the international exit code for North America; that part may be different depending where you're dialing from).

Comment: "The exchange in question is likely Kraken, which was meant to redistribute the funds once a decision was made based on the last information on the matter, but the trustee doesn’t say what exchange was used or what process was used for the sale." https://www.trustnodes.com/2018/03/07/mt-gox-trustee-sold-half-billion-dollars-worth-bitcoin-bitcoin-cash